# Sort and Take N from dictionary value in C#

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, take

I have a dictionary in C#.

```
Dictionary originalMap = new Dictionary<string, List<CustomObject>>();

originalMap contents: 
"abc" -> {CustomObject1, CustomeObject2, ..CustomObject100};
"def" -> {CustomObject101,CustomObject102, CustomObject103};
```

Now, finally I want to make sure that the count of all custome objects above does not exceed a limit - say 200.
While doing this, I want to make sure that I take top 200 ranked object (sorted by Score porperty).

I tried below but it doesn't work. It returns same number of objects.

```
var modifiedMap = new Dictionary<string, IList<CustomObject>>(CustomObject);

modifiedMap = originalMap.OrderByDescending(map => map.Value.OrderByDescending(customObject => customObject.Score).ToList().Take(200))
                 .ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to limit the total number in the dictionary to 200 or the total number per key to 200?

Comment: (My answer assumes a limit per key - if that's not what you want, please clarify your question.)

Comment: It was per key, thanks for the concern :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're only performing the limit part while doing the ordering - not when you actually create the new dictionary.

It sounds like you want something like:

```cs
var modifiedMap = originalMap.ToDictionary(
    pair => pair.Key,
    pair => pair.Value.OrderByDescending(co => co.Score).Take(200).ToList());
```

Note that ordering the dictionary entries themselves would be pointless, as `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` is inherently not an ordered collection.